# How to create the same element within a loop in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any way to create the same element several times within a loop in Flutter? The user will enter a quantity (number) and I need to create that same quantity of inputs (to fill an array later). I've been searching for it for hours and I didn't find anything that would help.

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement the logic you want through a number of steps:

1. Turn the widget into `StatefulWidget` if it doesn't.
2. Implement the field where the user would enter the quantity.
3. Create a property to hold the quantity and start it with zero:

`int quantity = 0`

4. Implement the widget of the single item of which you want to be repeated.
5. Use the feature called "collection for" in Dart which uses for loop inside a List to create its values:

```
Column(
    children:[
        for( int i = 0 ; i < quantity ; i++)
            // Here add the widget you created for the single item...
            // e.g.
            Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 100,
                color: Colors.red
            )
    ]
), // Note: Initially it will not create 
   // any widget because we initialized the quantity variable with 0...
```

6. When the user enters the quantity, if you have something like confirm button or any sort of that, then assign the entered quantity to the property we created and don't forget to call `setState()` to rebuild the UI and let the for loop run again with the new quantity:

```
TextField(
    ...
    onChanged: (value){
        setState((){
            quantity = int.parse(value);
            // Note this line can fail when the user
            // enters a non-number value, so be careful and add the validation...
        });
    }   
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way. I have added comment into my code so that you can understand.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Demo(),
    );
  }
}

class Demo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DemoDataState createState() => _DemoDataState();
}

class _DemoDataState extends State<Demo> {
  List<Widget> _listItems = []; // to store the list items
  final _textEditingController = TextEditingController();

  void addItems(int repeatCount) {
    List<Widget> _temp = []; // temporary var to store items

    for (int i = 0; i < repeatCount; i++) { // loop till user entered number
      _temp.add(Text('Hello again')); // and add our widget to the list
    }

    // setState() will cause rebuild which will regenerate the list
    setState(() {
      _listItems.addAll(_temp); // finally add the _temp items into our main ( _listItems ) list variable
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          title: Text(
            "Demo",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(children: [
          TextField(
              controller: _textEditingController,
              onSubmitted: (String value) async { // after user number enters and click on done, this will be called
                if (value != null) {
                  addItems(int.parse(value)); // call the method to add number of element with user entered number
                }
              }),
          ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: _listItems.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Text('Hello $index'); // show the item
              })
        ])));
  }
}
```

Comment: Nothing worked with TextFiels which was what I needed, I had a problem with their controllers, but thanks guys thanks for trying to help